# Why add one more block of memory after dynamic memory allocation using realloc()?

Tags: arrays, c, string, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

The Sorting Array of Strings problem on Hackerrank has a loop to take input in a 2D array of strings. This loop dynamically allocates memory for each string with `malloc()`, takes input with `scanf()` and then reallocates the block with one more block.

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
  
char** arr;
arr = (char**)malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
  
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    *(arr + i) = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", *(arr + i));
    *(arr + i) = realloc(*(arr + i), strlen(*(arr + i)) + 1);
}
```

link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sorting-array-of-strings/problem

I have two questions:

1. Why is that extra block of memory used for?
2. Why is it using `scanf()` to take a string input and not `fgets()`? Isn't it a good practice?

Answer (score 1):

1. `*(arr + i) = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));`

   It's allocating 1024 `char`s for the i-th string because the max string length is known

   `*(arr + i) = realloc(*(arr + i), strlen(*(arr + i)) + 1);`

   while here it's resizing the block to fit exactly the size of the string i
2. Since a single word is provided in input `scanf` will suffice